# How to sort a dataset in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Tuple Dataset of the form DataSet>. I wish to sort the "entire" Dataset on field String and then get only the Long values in a file. Flink does provide sort-partition but that does not help here as I need to sort the Dataset completely.

Comment: A sample of the data before and after?  Maybe the code you have tried so far and how it failed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also use `sortPartition()` to sort the complete `DataSet` if you set the parallelism to `1`:

```
DataSet<Tuple2<String, Long>> data = ...
DataSet<Tuple2<String, Long>> sorted = data
  .sortPartition(0, Order.ASCENDING).setParallelism(1); // sort in one partition
DataSet<Long> longs = sorted.map(new LongExtractor());  // map to extract long
```

Comment: so, if the parallelism is not set to 1, then the whole dataset will not be completely sorted? In detail, if parallelism is set to 2 then each worker will sort its data but across partitions there will be no ascending order?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you range partition the DataSet on the sort key before calling `sortPartition`, the sorted partitions will be disjoint ranges.