# How to preserve sort order after joining two datasets in apache flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I am using apache flink for batch processing and I have a sorted 10 element dataset which consists of movie id and its ratings and it looks something like (movie_id, rating)

```
(318,4.429022082018927)
(858,4.2890625)
(2959,4.272935779816514)
(1276,4.271929824561403)
(750,4.268041237113402)
(904,4.261904761904762)
(1221,4.25968992248062)
(48516,4.252336448598131)
(1213,4.25)
(912,4.24)
```

I have to join this dataset with a movie data set which has movie id and the movie names like

```
(1285,Heathers (1989))
(1286,Somewhere in Time (1980))
(1287,Ben-Hur (1959))
(1288,This Is Spinal Tap (1984))
```

The code I am using to join is

```
movies.join(sorted)  // sorted represents sorted ratings dataset
                .where(0) // joining movie_id of movies to movie_id of ratings
                .equalTo(0)
                .with(new JoinFunction<Tuple2<Long, String>, Tuple2<Long, Double>, Tuple3<Long, String, Double>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple3<Long, String, Double> join(
                            Tuple2<Long, String> movie,
                            Tuple2<Long, Double> rating) throws Exception {
                        return new Tuple3<>(movie.f0, movie.f1, rating.f1);
                    }
                }).print();
//movies row : movie_id, movie name
//sorted row: movie_id, rating
```

When I print this dataset, my output is in random order like,

```
(904,Rear Window (1954),4.261904761904762)
(318,Shawshank Redemption, The (1994),4.429022082018927)
(48516,Departed, The (2006),4.252336448598131)
(858,Godfather, The (1972),4.2890625)
(2959,Fight Club (1999),4.272935779816514)
(912,Casablanca (1942),4.24)
(1276,Cool Hand Luke (1967),4.271929824561403)
```

Here I would expect movie Shawshank Redemption id 318 to be placed above Rear Window id 904 based on descending order of rating. I am following a course online and the dataset is available [here](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/). Can anyone help me with correcting my logic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a dataset in Apache Flink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156483/how-to-sort-a-dataset-in-apache-flink)

Comment: No, my problem is joining in flink is destroying the sort order, I have got the sort order right as shown in the first set of numbers

Comment: Exactly. The join operation overwrites the sort operation. Then you have to sort it again.

Comment: Okay I did not know that,  is there any documentation link I can refer?

Comment: Search for `sort partition` at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/